# Date Picker is not getting populated with date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is HTML input tag

```
<label for="release">release Date</label>
<input type="date" name="releasedate" id = "release_date">
```

I am trying to populate the fields in the update form All the other values are getting populated except Date.I am able to console the date but i am not able to populate in the text field

```
function _update(id){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://localhost:8888/booksdetail/'+id,
                    method:'GET',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#name').val(data.name);
                        $('#description').val(data.description);
                        $('#author').val(data.author);
                        $('#price').val(data.price);
                        $("#release_date").val(data.release_date);
                        console.log(data.release_date);


                    },
                    error: function(error){
                            alert(error);
                    }
                })
            }
```

In console Date and time are printed but in my  date field only date should get populated.

Comment: Is the field name in your JSON response really `data.relasedate` and not `data.releasedate`?

Comment: You are logging console.log(data.release_date); and you are using data.relasedate to set the value

Answer (score 0):

Your releasedate spelling is wrong

```
$("#release_date").val(data.relasedate);
```

Shouldn't it be

```
$("#release_date").val(data.releasedate);
```

Comment: or data.release_date :) or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the format of date which you are getting from your api and the format which you are using in your date picker are same ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi its because input Date format need formated date value like e.g: yyy-mm-dd need to be same as datepicked

I put to you a exemple to change val of format at fidle

```
 <label for="release">release Date</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" name="trip" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/37rLsbp5/

you can also check https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date

Comment: In my console it gets printed like this "1997-03-22T18:30:00.000+0000".How to convert it to the yyy-mm-dd.